# anti-forgery token issue in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cross-platform, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I’m working on ACE Rules compliance, wherein I have to apply anti-forgery token to prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF). The following are the changes I made:1)      In Controller: I decorated the action method with the token as shown
[image]

. 2)      In View, I added the token in a form along with the action name and controller name.  
[image]

3)      Made the following changes in the index.js file:  Observation: On debugging it was found that the call to reqMan.Exec() never succeeds.In ReqMan.js, where ajax() call is made, it always fails.
[image]

4)      On click of OK, when the reqMan.Exec() call is made, it navigates to the error page with the following message:  5)      I also tried changing the objData : $(‘form’).serialize(), which also doesn’t work and gives the following error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't just a typo. I see in your example that you have written `__RequestVerificationT*O*ken` instead of `__RequestVerificationToken` when creating your `updateModel`in Javascript.